# Cannot assign output to variable in event fired function in python

Tags: python

Looking to assign a variable with the output of a function fired by an event in ipyleaflet. I can get the function to print a lat/lng from a dictionary input but I can't assign that to a variable. The printed output from the function snippet below is like [0.5090396, 34.5731341]. Slightly new to this.

```
m.add_control(search)

def on_found(**adr):
    for ky, val in adr.items():
        if ky == 'location':
            print(val)

search.on_location_found(on_found)
```

Whole code:

```
from ipyleaflet import Map, Marker, MarkerCluster, SearchControl, AwesomeIcon, basemaps

lat, lon = 52.4912, -1.9348 

m = Map(basemap = basemaps.Esri.WorldStreetMap, center=(lat,lon), zoom=3)

marker = Marker(icon=AwesomeIcon(name="check", marker_color='green', icon_color='darkgreen'))

search = SearchControl( 
    position="topleft", 
    url='https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q={s}', 
    zoom=5, 
    marker=marker) 

m.add_control(search)

def on_found(**adr):
    for ky, val in adr.items():
        if ky == 'location':
            print(val)

search.on_location_found(on_found)

m
```

Comment: inside function you have to use `global` to assign value to external variables. But usually assigning to external variable in function fired by event can be useless - if you want to do something with this value then do it directly inside this function.

Comment: One thing to note is that you are not using a `return` statement but a `print` statement in your function. I am not sure if this will fix it as I am not experienced in ipyleaflet.

Comment: Sorry yes I used the return statement and when trying to access the variable I got 'None'

Comment: @furas sounds like a good idea hopefully. I want to take the lat/lng pair and feed them into a API post request that returns a score for the lat/lng.

Comment: `return` in function executed by event is useless. First: you never know when it will run this function but rest of code runs at start - before this function is executed (and even when global variable is still empty). Second: framework/module runs this function somewhere in inner code and it doesn't know what to do with returned value - so it skips it. If you want to use value with API then do it inside this function `on_found`

Comment: ok great thanks again. Feel free to add this as the answer and I will accept it.